# ORIKA MAPPER: what is best way to bind default map value?

Tags: orika

I am looking for simple in-line way (without converters) how to:

- insert a String value 'RELEASED' in case if document.status == null.
- insert a String value 'FINISHED' just like constant value

something like this:

```
 mapFactory
      .classMap(RequestDto.class, Context.class)
                    .field("document.status", "group.doc.status:*RELEASED*")
                    .field("",                "group.mdk.status:*FINISHED*") //always finished
```